# ActionScript2 Base64 encode/decode binary data

Tags: javascript, actionscript, encoding, base64

I have an actionscript 2 code that uses base64 to encode/decode incoming data. problem is that data is binary and includes null (0 characters), actionscript 2 fails when handing null to charCodeAt.

I figured what I need is an actionscript 2 lib that can do base64 encoding/decoding on an array rather than a String.

can anyone point me to one ?

this is very important,

thanks

Comment: Sounds interesting, maybe you know of some Actionscript tutorial which explains how it works in Flash?

Answer (score 0):

Run your request through a custom proxy..

You can do what you need to do with your favorite language and then send back to the AS3 application.

RUBY, PHP, and JAVA can all do what you are saying.

I use PHP, curl in the data, encode and then respond to the requesting application.

Read about proxy models ... its simple and highly effective for remote object parsing and encoding.

Its way cleaner than having to rely on client side parsing and encoding from old and undocumented AS2 swc / libs.

I advise looking up RDS in AS2

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as2/reference/addendum/WS3fd35e178bb08cb31e63e3d124b63c3af7-8000.html